# How to evaluate expression in handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I need to evaluate an expression which I am supposed to append.

`eAddressType` can be `M`, `E`, `PH` or `FX`

What will be the best way to evaluate the expression `initData.alternateContactLabelM` using a combination of (`alternateContactLabel` + `eAddressType`)?

```
<ux-list-item primary_text="{{initData.alternateContactLabel + this.implEAddressType.eAddressType}}"
                              secondary_text="{{this.value}}"
                              cta="{text: '{{initData.uxButtonChangeLabel}}', onclick: 'alternateContactClick:{{index}},{{this.implEAddressType.eAddressType}}'}"
                              ariaLabel="{{initData.uxButtonChangeLabel}} {{initData.alternateContactLabelPH}}">
</ux-list-item>
```

In JSON I have:

```
"initData": {
    "alternateContactLabelM":"Alternative Mobile Number (SMS)",
    "alternateContactLabelE":"Alternative Email Address",
    "alternateContactLabelPH":"Alternative Contact Number",
    "alternateContactLabelFX":"Alternative Fax",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a combination of a custom helper to produce the name of the key and the [built-in lookup helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) to get the *value* of that property on the `initData` object.

Handlebars helpers for string concatentation have doubtlessly been written before, but I will write my own simple implementation here:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('concat', function () {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1).join('');
});
```

This helper concatenates all of the parameters passed to it except for the last parameter, which we know is the Handlebars `options` object.

We can now use this helper in our template to dynamically return the key name. We will then use the lookup helper to find the value of `initData` at that key:

```
primary_text="{{lookup initData (concat 'alternateContactLabel' implEAddressType.eAddressType)}}"
```

For a working example, please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/b3eez2vv/).